# Outlook VBA Macro Prevent Running Specified Email Account

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I have been using Office 365 Outlook account. Now I configured 3 email accounts. since I created a VBA macro script. I don't want this script was running in all of my email accounts. I want to run VBA Script in specified accounts only. How can achieve that?

For example: Assume my three accounts

- test@test.com,
- test1@test.com,
- test2@test.com.

I want to execute my VBA code only in

- test@test.com,
- test1@test.com,

Not running VBA script at

- test2@test.com

My Code:-

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Dim prompt As String
    Dim strMsg As String

    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

    Set recips = Item.Recipients
    For Each recip In recips
        Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
        If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@newsdozens.com") = 0 Then
        If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@newsdozens2.com") = 0 Then
        If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@bnewstest.com") = 0 Then
            strMsg = strMsg & "   " & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) & vbNewLine
        End If
        End If
        End If
    Next

    If strMsg <> "" Then
        prompt = "This email will be sent outside of newsdozens.com to:" & vbNewLine & strMsg & "Do you want to proceed?"
        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you currently run that macro?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you are using.

Comment: yeag i have added my used code

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you only want to run your code against a particular message store? Or only when an email from a particular account is received? Or when it is sent using a particular account?

Answer (score 0):

To selectively start a macro, you could do something like the following:

```
Dim Session As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Accounts As Outlook.Accounts
Dim currentAccount As Outlook.Account

Set Session = Application.Session    
Set Accounts = Session.Accounts

For Each currentAccount In Accounts                    
    Debug.Print currentAccount.SmtpAddress

    If currentAccount.SmtpAddress <> "test2@test.com" Then
        '  call your macro
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of getting sender information. This should work for either EX or SMTP addresses.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Debug.Print Item.SenderEmailAddress
    ' use text from the debug.print, that is unique to the account
    If InStr(Item.SenderEmailAddress, "test2") Then Exit Sub

    ' code here for all other accounts

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the Sender's email address in the `ItemSend` event and cancel any further actions if no VBA macros should be run for a particular account:

```
 Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

   If InStr(LCase(Item.SenderEmailAddress), "test2@test.com") = 0 Then Exit Sub

   Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
   Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
   Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
   Dim prompt As String
   Dim strMsg As String

   Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

  Set recips = Item.Recipients
  For Each recip In recips
    Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor
    If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@newsdozens.com") = 0 Then
    If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@newsdozens2.com") = 0 Then
    If InStr(LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)), "@bnewstest.com") = 0 Then
        strMsg = strMsg & "   " & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) & vbNewLine
    End If
    End If
    End If
  Next

  If strMsg <> "" Then
    prompt = "This email will be sent outside of newsdozens.com to:" & vbNewLine & strMsg & "Do you want to proceed?"
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```